# Adding values to a state array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to accomplish two things. One, onClick, I am adding values to a state property, cardPairs. I made a copy of the state object and used concat to add a value. It takes me three clicks to create a match. The first time I click, I get the empty array, then on two subsequent correct clicks, I'll have a match. Using push doesn't work on my copy, I get a "could not consume" error and when trying push, I get "object is not extensible". How can I match on two clicks?
The second issue is removing the matched items from the UI.

```
class CardCollectionTwo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hidden: false,
      cardPairs: []
    };
    this.compareCards = this.compareCards.bind(this);
  }

  compareCards(e) {
    const pairs = Object.freeze(this.state.cardPairs)
    console.log(pairs)
    this.setState({ cardPairs: pairs.concat(e.target.value) });
    console.log(this.state);
    if(pairs[0] === pairs[1] && pairs.length!== 0){
      console.log('MATCH')
    }else if(pairs.length === 2){
        this.setState(prevState => ({ cardPairs: [] }))
   }
 }
 render() {
    let cards = this.props.cardsEasy["cards"].map((item, index) => {
      return (
    <button
      style={btn}
      value={item}
      id={item}
      onClick={this.compareCards}
      key={item + index}
    >
      {item}
    </button>
  );
});
return <CardTwo cards={cards} />;
 }
   }

export default CardCollectionTwo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Push and Object.freeze()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

`Object.freeze()` prevents elements from being added to the array (in your case, via push). `Object.freeze()` prevents additions, removals, and changes to whatever it is applied to (array pushes/modifications, objects, etc). To properly copy, you can use the `Array.slice()` (`this.state.cardPairs.slice()`), which returns a shallow copy of the source.

`concat` does not modify the array, while `push` does. `concat()` returns a new array that is the combination of 2 arrays, while `push()` adds an element to the current array. This is why `push()` does not work on a frozen object, while `concat` does.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answering the matching question:

```
if (pairs[0] === pairs[1] && pairs.length!== 0){
  console.log('MATCH')
} else if(pairs.length === 2){
    this.setState(prevState => ({ cardPairs: [] }))
}
```

There is an error in your logic. Basically, you concatenate the new pair value and commit it to your state (via `this.setState({ cardPairs: pairs.concat(e.target.value })`). However, this `if` conditional is relying on that `e.target.value`, and so the `pairs` variable is outdated.

Also, it seems code-wise you are strictly only comparing the first two elements of the array, which leads to the infinite mismatch problem.

## Solution

We can take a different approach: Firstly, whenever a new, unique value is clicked, add it to the array. However, if we come upon a value that is already in the array, then that means we have a match. We can then filter out the element (there is probably a remove function that'd work well too). That means that our pairs will always only contain unique values, and will drop unique values whenever there are matches.

```
const pairs = this.state.cardPairs.slice();
if (pairs.includes(e.target.value)) {
  console.log("Match");
  this.setState({ cardPairs: pairs.filter(el => el != e.target.value )})
} else {
  // Otherwise, add more elements to the list.
  this.setState({ cardPairs: pairs.concat(e.target.value) });
}
```

User clicks 1:
[1]

User clicks 1 again:
[]

User clicks 0, 1:
[0,1]

User clicks 1:
[0]

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/4jmjp3l94x

Comment: I did that already, and it still takes three clicks for the match const pairs = this.state.cardPairs.slice()

Comment: Hi, I updated the answer just now. In your if conditional, you are using the old array that does not have the new pair concatenated to it.

Comment: I did what you said, still three clicks...    [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/oq3113vnlz)

Comment: Sorry, please reexamine the code. I sent you buggy code, but now it should work. https://codesandbox.io/s/2xrz1j8mmn Here is a live example too. Basically, I provided you the wrong code for using the this.setState callback. To use the new state, you just have to recall this.state.cardPairs.

However, I think I am not answering the question correctly (for removing the matched elements).

Comment: You want to match any duplicates in the array right? Like if the user clicks 0->0, match. But if the user clicks 0->1->0, remove both 0's? If so, we will have to change the answer to not rely on simply the first 2 elements of the array..

Comment: : ) now the issue is that we have capability of unlimited mismatches and the pairs/ state array dont clear